# JSHINT failing for below line, receiving error "Identifier 'mb_YTPlayer' is not in camel case."

Tags: javascript, jshint

```
 $('.player').mb_YTPlayer();
```

this line is giving error as "Identifier 'mb_YTPlayer' is not in camel case.

Comment: where you see this error in the editor or some online jshint service.

Comment: I am getting this in grunt jshint service and not in  the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you cannot change that strange name, just ignore linting on that specific line using:

```
/* jshint ignore:start */
$('.player').mb_YTPlayer(); 
/* jshint ignore:end */
```

Or even:

```
$('.player').mb_YTPlayer(); // jshint ignore:line
```

See the section about `ignore` in the [JSHint documentation](http://jshint.com/docs/).

Comment: How to go  about these: 

 if (typeof(errorHandler) === 'function'){
            errorHandler(data.GMRXResponse.Status.Description);
          }
          else{
            alert(response.data.GMRXResponse.Status.Description);
          } 
Errors  on Jshint:  
 'errorHandler' is not defined.
 'data' is not defined.
 'alert' is not defined.

Comment: Are you sure these are defined? You might try `var errorHandler = errorHandler || 'Add default value here';` And `alert` should be replaced with `window.alert`.